# Loop-Program possible modifications

Tags: turing-machines

Recently learning some core register modifications and made a loop-program that calculates the gcd. Any way to improve/shorten this version I came up with? Input for x and y go into x1 and x2 and output will be in x3. Example gcd(x1, x2) = x3
If x1 = 12, x2 = 15, then x3 = 3

Okay,now my code:

X3 := x1;

X4 := x2;

X5 := x3 + x4; //not sure if testing for bigger number is better as a loop count

LOOP x5 DO

```
X5 := x3 + x4;

X5 := 1 - x5;

Loop x5 DO

   X5 := x4;

   X4 := x3;

   X3 := x5

END;

X3 := x3 - x4;

X5 := 1 - x3;

LOOP x5 DO

   X3 := x4

END;
```

END;

X4 := 0;

X5 := 0;

I hope that someone here knows about loop programs. I know they are old fashioned.